# Xcode doesn't throw warning for capturing strong self

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a block that cause some issues. Usually Xcode shows me where potential issues can be happened by throwing warning next to line [self method], but right now it does not work.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PNTabCell *collectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PNTabCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    collectionViewCell.didPressedCloseButton = ^()
    {
        [self didCloseTab];
    };

    return collectionViewCell;
}
```

But my question is how to switch on automatically warning notification for the potential leak lines as this one [self method]

Answer (score 0):

Capturing strong self is not a problem. Creating retain cycles is a problem. Does this create a retain cycle? It doesn't look like it. It's just a chain markFilePathAsActive->block->self. self will be released once the method you are calling has finished. So there doesn't seem to be any reason for a warning.

Comment: I have modified question and while I use this code the self never will be released.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a retain cycle to me, so I don't think there's a need for a warning.

And I don't think Xcode can figure out all retain cycles by default, with the normal warning system (the yellow warnings), and I don't think you can make it do that.

But you can try to run the Analyzer from time to time. It's quite powerful. Go to Product -> Analyze. That will run a static analysis of your code, and will detect possible memory leaks, dead stores, not calling super in view lifecycle methods, and others. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Analyze/Analyze.html.

And you can also try to update the analyzer to a newer version, as instructed here: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html

Comment: I think some understanding issues I have modified question, Do you think [self method] will not affect ?

Comment: Ask yourself: Is there a cycle? The block has a strong reference to self, but that's fine unless self has a strong reference to the block as well, and it doesn't look like it has. It's _cycles_ that cause problems. self -> block -> self or block -> self -> block. block -> self is not a cycle, therefore no problem.

Comment: @gnasher729, but I have debug my code with instrument and the object self was still in the memory, but when I have switched to using week the problem was solved

Comment: @gnasher729 oh, seems you are right I will modify my question. In my case I've described there is no cycles really

Comment: In the current edit, there is a cycle. Self presumably retains the collection view, which retains the collection view cell, which retains the block, which retains self. `weakSelf` will break the cycle.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg yep I understand the logic and thank you for answer, but the question is about warning that should be shown, but it this case parser ignore this block. I think maybe it is not easy to parse this error for Xcode

Comment: The issue is that the compiler can’t know that `collectionView` is also `self.collectionView`, and therefore can’t tell for certain that it is a cycle. If you were to refer to `self.collectionView` in the callback, and assign the block to that, I believe you would get a warning.